# How to use INSERT query to avoid duplicate entries in postgresql database tables

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

Hi..while using the follwing code i am getting duplicate entries in my table..
Please suggest some method to avoid such duplicate entries..!!

Is there any other mode of INSERT query to acheive duplication free tables..???

```
import psycopg2

def connect():
    con=psycopg2.connect("dbname='book_store' user='postgres' password='5283' host='localhost' port='5432' ")
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists books(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,title TEXT NOT NULL,author TEXT NOT NULL,year integer NOT NULL,isbn integer NOT NULL)")
    con.commit()
    con.close()

def insert(title,author,year,isbn):
    con=psycopg2.connect("dbname='book_store' user='postgres' password='5283' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO books(title,author,year,isbn) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)",(title,author,year,isbn))
    con.commit()
    con.close()


connect()
insert("the sun","helen",1997,23456777)
insert("the sun","helen",1997,23456777)
```

Here the same entry gets added again..where i want my code to neglect such duplication..!!!

Comment: There is nothing in your code that suggests multiple rows being inserted.. maybe you are seeing multiple entries because you are executing your code multiple times. Note that your `connect()` method creates the table only if it does not exist.

Comment: while executing "insert("the sun","helen",1997,23456777)" statement again ,the same data is getting added..

Comment: Then adding a [unique constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-constraints.html) to your table may be useful.

Comment: Hope this helps..Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

**Ideally there should be primary key or Unique key constraint defined on the table to avoid duplicates** but if you want to insert only if that record doesn't exists then you can use below **insert statement** with **select** & **where not exists** clause

```
INSERT INTO books(title,author,year,isbn) select @title,@author,@year,@isbn from books where 
 not exists (select 1 from books where title=@title and author=@author and year=@year and isbn=@isbn);
```

In where condition should check for **Primary** OR **Unique key** columns instead of all the columns.